# Error while adding DataSource in powerbi gateway using power shell

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-gateway

I am using powershell for .pbix to deployment in workspaces. As part of that i need to create SQL datasource under gateway for further use.
I am using powerbI rest API with service principle : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/create-datasource

Here is link for sample we can use in powershell: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-REST-API-via-Powershell-Create-Datasource/m-p/511934

I hope someone can help me here. Thanks in advance.

**I am getting thiserror:**
| Encountered errors when invoking the command: {   "code": "DM_GWPipeline_UnknownError",   "pbi.error": {     "code": "DM_GWPipeline_UnknownError",   
    | "parameters": {},     "details": [       {         "code": "DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage",         "detail": {           "type": 1,
    | "value": **"The parameter is incorrect.**\r\n"         }       },       {         "code": "DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult",         "detail": {
    | "type": 1,           "value": "-2146893785"         }       }     ],     "exceptionCulprit": 1   } }

Comment: Use a online JSON validator and see if your json contains errors.  You may have issues with nesting of single and double quotes.

Comment: I Checked json and that looks good.

Comment: You need to debug the server code.  Are you using a SQL Server database?  I can't tell if the error is occurring in the front end between the client and server, or the backend between the server and the database. SQL Server Management Studio in the explorer under management has log files which would give backend errors, but I do not know if the error is frontend or backend.